# Your request produced an error. [newNullResponse]?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

Error getting while clicking on the My iTunes application URL in any browser,
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/snapshare-lite/id409972682?mt=8

> Your request produced an error.
>
> [newNullResponse]

URL is working fine in iTunes in mac as well AppStore in iPhone.

This error occurred after uploading my application's new version.

Don't know what is happening, Did I miss something while uploading the app on AppStore?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mayur Question Edited...

Comment: From my iTunes account

Comment: Yes I get it from there, it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the other post:**

Spoke to Customer support today, who acknowledged a current known issue on their end and that engineer were "working on it".  Don't know how widespread or when it will be addressed.  Stressed to them this was holding up a product launch.  Been broken for at least days for me, hard to tell how much longer and how many of us it impacts.  Perhaps if affected developers would comment here we could raise the transparency.

It's hard to believe support is in the position of having to apologize without data.  I'd imagine that it doesn't impact too many people or it would be taken more seriously.  But for something to be broken for days normally would require an escalation.  Maybe one is happening and maybe one isn't.

But since the original post was a few years old, this current issue isn't the first time.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message when I wanted to upgrade the OS from the App store. I read in another forum that if you can try changing your payment info in the iTunes store, then try again. That worked for me. The error message disappeared and I was able to use the App store. I have no idea why that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to resolve the issue :

> - Logout from iTunes account
> - Restart your device or system (whatever you are using)
> - Clear browser cache
> - Now try to login again in iTunes

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, I followed all steps properly.

Comment: YES, I contact Apple Store and it's solved. Thanks for quick response. :)